# В первом списке должно быть больше элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x

подскажите, как в этом коде сделать, что б в первом списке выводило больше значений чем во втором?
изначальный список может быть больше, но при разделении в первом должно быть больше значений

```
    lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    my_list = len(lst)
    
    middle_list = my_list // 2
    
    first_list = lst[:middle_list]
    second_list = lst[middle_list:]
    
    print([first_list,second_list])

[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Выбрать `middle_list = my_list // 2 + 1`

Comment: `middle_list = (my_list + 1) // 2`

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы получить больше значений в первом списке, нужно изменить индексы среза в переменной first_list

```
first_list = lst[:middle_list+1]
```

```
middle_list = 3
```

В результате получим  [1, 2, 3, 4] и [5]